# My Game Character should teleport to the mouse pointer but it teleports far away from my mouse pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my Player Teleport to my mouse position but whenever I right click it seems to teleport far away from my camera and generally where my mouse pointer was.
I am not getting any error messages nor am I getting warnings.

for example, if I click in the middle of the screen with my mouse it will teleport to the center of the text Canvas.
I couldn't seem to find any solutions to my issue on the unity forums.
maybe someone here could help me

my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;
    public Transform player; //Variable for Teleport funktion
    void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform; //Finding the player (Teleport)
    }

    void fixedUpdate()
    {

        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {

            player.position = (Input.mousePosition); // teleporting

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
            Vector2 myPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            Vector2 direction = target - myPos;
            direction.Normalize();
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
            GameObject projectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet, myPos, rotation);
            projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * speed;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: immediately below your teleport code you have some shooting code, which *transforms* your `Input.mousePosition` from screen space to world space. given that you need this, why would it make sense to set `player.position` directly to screen space coordinates?

Comment: I really recommend you to store the `GetComponent` returns in variables for later use, because it can cause performance issues when used on update

Answer (score 2):

You just need to transform the input position from screen to world, like you did in your shooting code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    player.position = target; // teleporting

}
```